# Passing Session Object Using OpenStack - KeyStone

Tags: python, json, openstack, cherrypy, keystone

I'm trying to pass the session object from one file to another in order to use the same session object across all the different things I need to do (list/create VMs etc.) So far I've tried using Pickle (which hasn't worked as there is a lock instance on the object). I'm now trying to use Cherrypy to enable me to store the object as a cookie (which I'm already doing for name and fedid). But I'm getting an error which says the session object isn't JSON serializable.

How do I get past this error and is this the right way to go about passing session objects? If it's not the correct solution, how do I pass session objects (the documentation isn't exactly helpful)?

```
import cherrypy
import ldap
import xmlrpclib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from keystoneauth1 import loading
from keystoneauth1 import session as session
import novaclient.client as client
import json
import pickle


NOVA_VERSION="2.1"
KEYSTONE_URL = cherrypy.request.config.get("keystone")
OPENSTACK_HOST = cherrypy.request.config.get("openstack_host")
OPENSTACK_DEFAULT_DOMAIN = 
cherrypy.request.config.get("openstack_default_domain")
loader = loading.get_plugin_loader('password')
auth = loader.load_from_options(auth_url=KEYSTONE_URL, username=data.get("username"), password=data.get("password").replace(" ","%20"),user_domain_name=OPENSTACK_DEFAULT_DOMAIN)
sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
nova = client.Client(NOVA_VERSION,session=sess)
data = {
        'name'    : name,
        'fedid'   : data.get("username"),
        'sessionTest' : json.dumps(sess),
        'expires' : EXPIRE
    }
```

Error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
response.body = self.handler()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/jsontools.py", line 61, in json_handler
value = cherrypy.serving.request._json_inner_handler(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 34, in __call__
return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "/var/www/frontend/controllers/api/user.py", line 102, in PUT
'sessionTest' : json.dumps(sess),
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <keystoneauth1.session.Session object at 0x7f023003c710> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: can you share your imports? what module id session.Session from

Comment: Just added the imports in. I'll be honest, I'm not too sure how to find the module ID (I'm quite new to this). Cheers, Matt :)

Comment: the module is keystoneauth1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the `loader` object.

You should load the auth credentials at the reciever

you can pickle `loader` and the options but not the `auth` object

Comment: When I do that I'm getting a TypeError stating that I can''t pickle lock objects as I was when I previously tried using Pickle